# Authenticate a user with Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the login html page and an index html page but when i write down username and password the page only refresh without doing anything.
I use Django 2.x and Python 3.4

The code in login html:

```
      <form class="form-signin" action='{% url 'myapp:index' %}' method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <img class="mb-4" src='{% static 'app/img/logo.png' %}' alt="" width="300" height="100">

    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">mysite</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="username" id="inputUser" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus alt="" width="300" height="100">
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required alt="" width="300" height="100">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Accedi</button>
    </div>

  </form>
```

and here my view:

```
def index(request):
    username = request.post["username"]
    password = request.post["password"]
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return render(request, "myapp/index.html")
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

EDIT:

My error.log

> AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::1c06:8ac5:1b1e:aa2f. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>   [Thu Aug 02 12:35:17.911829 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4196:tid 452] AH00455: Apache/2.4.34 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Thu Aug 02 12:35:17.912829 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4196:tid 452] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Jul 11 2018 13:09:01
>   [Thu Aug 02 12:35:17.912829 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4196:tid 452] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\Apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache'
>   [Thu Aug 02 12:35:17.913829 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4196:tid 452] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2112
>   AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::1c06:8ac5:1b1e:aa2f. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>   AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::1c06:8ac5:1b1e:aa2f. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>   [Thu Aug 02 12:35:18.335853 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2112:tid 472] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

My access.log:

> myip - - [02/Aug/2018:12:35:28 +0200] "GET /myapp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2633
>   myip - - [02/Aug/2018:12:35:48 +0200] "POST /myapp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2633

EDIT2:
I changed in the url.py from path to url and resolve the problem...now the page load correctly, thanks to all of you

Comment: What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: I expect that when I click on "Accedi" the program verify that the user exist in the DB and if it is, load the index page

Comment: Any message in your server trace log?

Comment: I added the logs in the post

Answer (score 0):

```
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
```

No need to pass request as a parameter

```
user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
```

It may solve your error.

Another way- 
You can also refer this tutorial:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html

Comment: Delete the "request" does not solve the problem, I'll go read the link you suggested me

Comment: Also request.post change to request.POST(case sensitive).

Comment: There is nothing like <input type="username">   change to <input type="text">

Comment: I applied all the changes but with no effect at all

Comment: I think there is a server error refer this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190085/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-using-1

Comment: I changed, in the url.py, from path to url and resolve the problem...now the page load correctly, thanks to all of you